# Expected proportion of successes coming from a distinguished group

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Let $X$ be a binomial random variable with parameters $N_1, p_1$ and let $Y$ be a binomial random variable with parameters $N_2, p_2$.  Assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent.  Is there a nice way to calculate $\mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{X}{X+Y} \right]$?  (In order for this to exist let's just say that $0/0 = 1$).  Alternatively, if we assume $N_1$ and $N_2$ are large, is there a nice way to estimate it by approximating $X$ and $Y$ by corresponding normal distributions?

The interpretation/motivation for this question: suppose you have a pool of $N_1 + N_2$ people. Say $N_1$ of them are "special" and the other $N_2$ of them are "normal".  Each special person has a probability $p_1$ of completing a task, and each normal person has probability $p_2$ of completing the task.  Assume all the people are independent of each other.  Then if $X$ is the number of special people who complete the task and $Y$ is the number of normal people who complete the task, I am looking for the expected proportion of successes that came from special people.

**EDIT:** It's natural to expect that this quantity should be pretty close to $\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{\mathbb{E}[X+Y]}$.  It would be super cool to see an estimate of the difference between the two as $N_1, N_2 \to \infty$.

Comment: This doesn't address the specific mathematical question, you might want to justify to yourself why you want $E[\frac{X}{X+Y}]$ rather than $E[X]/E[X+Y]$. An approximation that relates these two quantities can be found [here](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~hseltman/files/ratio.pdf).

Comment: $$
\operatorname E\left( \frac X{X+Y} \right) + \operatorname E\left( \frac Y{X+Y} \right) = \operatorname E\left( \frac X{X+Y} + \frac Y{X+Y} \right) =1 .
$$
The first term on the left must depend on $N_1,N_2,p_1,p_2$ in such a way that
\begin{align}
\bullet & \text{ If $N_1,N_2$ are interchanged with each other and likewise $p_1,p_2,$} \\
& \text{ the value of the first term above must become that of the second; and} \\ {} \\
\bullet & \text{ The sum of the two functions of $N_1,N_2,p_1,p_2$ must simplify to $1.$}
\end{align}

Comment: But on account of $P(X+Y=0)>0$ none of these expectations exist.

Comment: @BruceET Oops, edited to account for that

Comment: Is this a mathematical exercise or do you have some practical application in mind?

Comment: Just an exercise.  I'm TAing a class that gave this question as a homework exercise and had $E[X]/E[X+Y]$ as the intended answer.  But that's a different interpretation of the question, somehow I think it would be more satisfying to understand the true expected proportion

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you consider simulation to be 'nice', but it can easily give
an approximate solution for a particular practical application where all four parameters are known.

However, a rigorous analytic discussion has to address that the expectation does not exist because of the
tiny probability (even with large $n_1, n_2)$ that the denominator can be $0.$
Perhaps the comment of @angryavian is a more realistic approach.

Let $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(16, .4)$ and $Y \sim \mathsf{Binom}(25, .3).$
Then $E\left(\frac{X}{X+Y}\right) = 0.4622\pm 0.0002.$

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rbinom(10^6, 16, .4)
y = rbinom(10^6, 25, .3)
mean(x/(x+y))  
[1] 0.4622126
2*sd(x/(x+y))/sqrt(10^6)
[1] 0.0002267313  # 95% margin of simulation error
```

Comment: Would this count as a solution? It doesn't say how the answer depends on $N_i, p_i,\, i=1,2. \qquad$

Comment: Because of the possibility of a 0 denominator, I don't suppose any 'solution' is truly satisfactory. Simulation might be of some use in a practical situation where 0 counts are ignored or don't actually exist. In my example, `dbinom(0,16, .4)*dbinom(0, 25, .3)` returns `3.783302e-08`.

Comment: The proximity of this number to $0.64/(0.64+0.75) \approx 0.46$ should be said something about. $\qquad$

Comment: I've edited the question to say that we'll just use a convention $0/0=1$ in order to force the expectation to exist